# How to make menu links clickable and do a specific task in nextjs and daisyui?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, backend, daisyui

Im using nextjs, so its Typescript. I have the following code from daisyui , its a file tree , my question how can i make each file in the tree clickable like downloading a file oir displaying a text from another file ..etc . The filetree is availabvle here: https://daisyui.com/components/menu/ and called "File Tree"

i saved in a file called filetree.tsx . For example , i renamed "Project-final.psd" to Info , so when i click info i use a function from another file to display the info. I put it in a curly bracket.

filetree.tsx :

```
import  Display  from './info';



export default function Filetree() {
  return (

////////

<summary>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-4 h-4"><path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M2.25 12.75V12A2.25 2.25 0 014.5 9.75h15A2.25 2.25 0 0121.75 12v.75m-8.69-6.44l-2.12-2.12a1.5 1.5 0 00-1.061-.44H4.5A2.25 2.25 0 002.25 6v12a2.25 2.25 0 002.25 2.25h15A2.25 2.25 0 0021.75 18V9a2.25 2.25 0 00-2.25-2.25h-5.379a1.5 1.5 0 01-1.06-.44z" /></svg>
        Dorks Lists
      </summary>
      <ul>
        <li><a onClick={info}>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-4 h-4"><path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M19.5 14.25v-2.625a3.375 3.375 0 00-3.375-3.375h-1.5A1.125 1.125 0 0113.5 7.125v-1.5a3.375 3.375 0 00-3.375-3.375H8.25m2.25 0H5.625c-.621 0-1.125.504-1.125 1.125v17.25c0 .621.504 1.125 1.125 1.125h12.75c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125V11.25a9 9 0 00-9-9z" /></svg>
          Info
        </a></li>
        <li><a>

///////
```

The function that displays it if saved in called display:

```
export default function Display() {
  const myinfo = info.map(data =>
    <ul key={data.id}>
      
      <p>
        <li><b>Vendor name: {data.vendor}</b></li>
       <li> <b>Company: {data.company}</b></li>
       <li> <b>Details: {data.details}</b></li>
       <li> <b>Type: {data.type}</b></li>
       <li><a href={data.link}>URL: {dork.Link}</a></li>
       <br></br>
       
      </p>
    </ul>
  );
  return (
   <>
   <article>
      <h2>The result is:</h2>
      <br></br>
      <ul>{listdorks}</ul>
    </article>


</>
  );
}
```